# How to remove warning: Large title font text style before iOS 11.0 [5]

Tags: ios, xcode, warnings

So in our xcode project we get following error when building our project: `Large title font text style before iOS 11.0 [5]`.

[image]

Any ideas on how to get rid of it?

Our deployment target is iOS 10.0 if it matters.

**More info (issue navigator didn't show this initially):**

It seems to be something from a storyboard:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the issue navigator finally wanted to play ball and helped me locate the issue. Apparently using the font `Large title` in a storyboard was the issue. Hope this helps someone else.